# Throwing error in @WebServlet leaks class path in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a web servlet marked with `@WebServlet` and I want to throw an error in it.

I tried doing this as a test:

```
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "bad request");
}
```

And while it works, the response json doesn't look right. It exposes the class path:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-11-11T11:49:11.012+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException: 400 BAD_REQUEST \"bad request.\"",
    "path": "/path_to_servlet"
}
```

I was expecting the response to look like this (the way it would if thrown from a `@RestController`):

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-11-11T11:49:11.012+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "bad request.",
    "path": "/path_to_servlet"
}
```

I then tried `throw new ServletException("bad request");` and this was the result:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-11-11T11:49:11.012+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "jakarta.servlet.ServletException: bad request",
    "path": "/path_to_servlet"
}
```

That also does not look right.

I have `server.error.include-message: always` set so I can see the message in my `application.properties` but every other property is set to the default value.

How can I throw a simple HTTP error in a web servlet so the response json is like using `ResponseStatusException` with the status set properly and not leak the class path?

Comment: It doesn't expose the classpath it just shows the name of the exception. Servlets aren't handlers in the sense of Spring and thus don't get the same exception handling approach so the `@ExceptionHandler` instances don't apply. Also why write a servlet in the first place instead of a controller?

Comment: @M.Deinum That makes sense. The reason I am using a servlet is that app engine task handlers recommend them. https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-handlers